# Ignore Whitespace Within Environment

Tags: spacing

I'm using the [bnf package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/latex-bnf.html) to format a context-free grammar in one of my documents. I'm finding that any whitespace will be reflected in the output. I would like to keep the whitespace in the code for readability but have it removed in the output. Is there a way to make this happen?

```
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{bnf}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
[(colon){$\rightarrow$}]
[(semicolon)$|$]
[(comma){}]
[(period){\\}]
[(quote){\begin{bf}}{\end{bf}}]
[(nonterminal){$\langle$}{$\rangle$}]

<rule-working>:<formats>,<correctly>;<without>,<whitespace>.
<rule-not-working> : <formats> , <incorrectly> ; <with> , <whitespace> .

\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\catcode32=9\relax` (or `` \catcode`\ =9\relax ``) will make TeX ignore all spaces in the current group/environment. You could define your own environment and add it and `{grammar}` to it.

```
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{bnf}

\newenvironment{Grammar}{%
\catcode32=9\relax
\begin{grammar}%
}{%
\end{grammar}
}

\begin{document}

% Either
\begin{grammar}
[(colon){$\rightarrow$}]
[(semicolon)$|$]
[(comma){}]
[(period){\\}]
[(quote){\begin{bf}}{\end{bf}}]
[(nonterminal){$\langle$}{$\rangle$}]
\catcode32=9\relax

<rule-working>:<formats>,<correctly>;<without>,<whitespace>.
<rule-not-working> : <formats> , <incorrectly> ; <with> , <whitespace> .

\end{grammar}

% or
\begin{Grammar}
[(colon){$\rightarrow$}]
[(semicolon)$|$]
[(comma){}]
[(period){\\}]
[(quote){\begin{bf}}{\end{bf}}]
[(nonterminal){$\langle$}{$\rangle$}]

<rule-working>:<formats>,<correctly>;<without>,<whitespace>.
<rule-not-working> : <formats> , <incorrectly> ; <with> , <whitespace> .

\end{Grammar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

As Joseph Wright pointed out there are more space-like characters you might also want to ignore:

```
\catcode9=9\relax     % Horizontal Tab
\endlinechar=-1\relax % No line endings
```

A space or non-expandable TeX command like `\relax` must follow the number so TeX knows to stop reading digits.

and maybe these (just to be on the save side):

```
\catcode10=9 %   New line
\catcode11=9 %   Vertical Tab 
\catcode12=9 %   Form Feed
\catcode13=9 %   Carriage Return
```

Comment: You'd probably want to cover tabs as well, plus make line-ends disappear (`\endlinechar=-1\relax`).

Comment: @Joseph: Indeed, I added these now plus some more.

Comment: @Joseph why not enclose it in `ExplSyntaxOn ...ExplSyntaxOff`, it is much simpler.

Comment: @Yiannis, in case you don't know: Joseph wasn't notified of your comment; only the first "@" does this. If your had _exchanged_ Martin und Joseph, both would have gotten a notification since the author of the post is _always_ notified.