# How the remove the space in the page header?

Tags: titles

I want to remove the spaces in the titlemark, such as "H O W", I want it show like "HOW", but I do not know how to do this?

Comment: Does the command \Let\String\Spacechar\Relax work?

Comment: Post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Without knowing your document class or other settings, I don't see how we could tell how it got like that in the first place.

Comment: @frabjous   Ok, let me give you an example, givan any string, say "H O W", we need to remove all the space in the string, namely, we want to obtain the straing "HOW", how should we do?

Comment: `{\catcode32=9\relax\catcode\`\ =9\relax H O W}` might work. But I'm not sure that's the right strategy because I don't understand the use case.

Comment: @frabjous  Thank you very much Fraabjous, what is meaning of {\catcode32=9\relax\catcode`\ =9\relax } ? could you explain？and how can test it?

Comment: I got that from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/ignore-whitespace-within-environment), but there are doubtless others here who could explain better than I.

Comment: Catcode is a complex topic, I'd remember reading the book for a comprehensive understanding. (there's [tex core - What are category codes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes) but I think it's easier to understand to just read the book)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value to the `\spaceskip` primitive register:

```
H O W                         % default spaces between letters H,O,W

{\spaceskip=1em\relax H O W}  % bigger spaces between letters H,O,W

{\spaceskip=1sp\relax H O W}  % no spaces between H,O,W, kerning disabled

{\catcode`\ =9\relax H O W}   % no spaces between H,O,W, kerning enabled
```

Note, that value `1sp` is "almost zero" but it isn't exactly zero because zero value means: use default space, no `\spaceskip` value. But this solution doesn't allow kerning.

If you want to have kerning activated then use the example from the last line. The spaces are completely ignored here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a very simple way to solve this problem by writing one command

```
\def\newdelespace{\let\yourspaceChar\relax},
```

here command `\yourspaceChar` is defined as follows

```
\def\yourspaceChar{\hskip \f@size \p@}
```

Then use the command `\newdelespace` anywhere you want to remove all its space! it works, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\def\yourspaceChar{\hskip \f@size \p@}
\def\newdelespace{\let\yourspaceChar\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
H\yourspaceChar O \yourspaceChar W

{\newdelespace H\yourspaceChar O\yourspaceChar W}
\end{document}
```

[image]